# Is it possible to use askubuntu Question/Answer for Ubuntu lessons

Tags: discussion, support

I will start teaching some students about Linux using Ubuntu and I was wondering if it could be possible to use askubuntu to answer some of their questions regarding Ubuntu and any problem they have found.

In the positive side, they have to know english to take the course so that saves me from worrying about the language barrier and is the main reason why I was thinking of using Askubuntu as a helping tool for various course related issues.

Comment: I don't see any problem except for you as a group to choose what account to use if you're gonna interact. Is there some particular aspect or problem that you think of since you ask?

Comment: Many common questions that I get asked are found in askubuntu so it would save me time just creating a list of them and telling the students to visit each questions link to find out more about something in particular. Also several questions are very detailed about where to configure something, how to install something, etc..

Comment: Then AU seems to be an excellent resource. If you need to print posts to hand out http://www.stackprinter.com may be of help.

Comment: @N.N. Thanks for sharing that...I never even knew that existed!

Comment: @WarriorIng64 It's also listed at http://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite where you can find more tools for SX.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Absolutely, that sounds great.

If you give them a quick run down of the FAQ, I don't foresee any problems.